# How to catch an interrupt (Control-C) in a script?

Tags: scripting, interruption

If a user hits Control-C when a script is running, they get an `Interrupt>` prompt, where they have to type `exit` or `quit` to return to the shell. I'd like to have the interpreter exit immediately when Control-C is hit. To this end, I'd like to catch the interrupt and run `Exit`. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a better option?

Comment: I don't have time to try this, but theoretically you can write [your own handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641182/how-can-i-catch-a-ctrl-c-event-c) for the Ctrl-C event and set it using a [LibraryLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/LibraryLink.html) routine.  Yes, this is a nasty hack ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an ugly hack that works, based directly [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641223/695132).  This doesn't work on Windows.

First create a LibraryLink function that can set an alternate signal handler:

```
<< CCompilerDriver`

handlerlib = "
  #include <signal.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

  // you may want to specialize this for SIGINT only
  void my_handler(int s){
             printf(\"Caught signal %d\\n\",s);
             exit(1); 
  }

  DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
  }

  DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
      return 0;
  }

  DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return;
  }

  DLLEXPORT void setHandler(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
     struct sigaction sigIntHandler;

     sigIntHandler.sa_handler = my_handler;
     sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
     sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;

     sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);

     return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
  }
  ";

CreateLibrary[handlerlib, "handlerlib"]
```

Once the library is compiled, you can use it in any Mathematica session on the same machine.

So just put this at the beginning of your script:

```
LibraryFunctionLoad["handlerlib", "setHandler", {}, "Void"][]
```

Now Ctrl-C will kill the script immediately.

You could suggest to support that this be the default behaviour when Mathematica is invoked using the `-script` option.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I need something similar.  One question I have about your code: how come the third argument to `LibraryFunctionLoad` is `{}`, and not the list of argument types for `setHandler`?

Comment: @kjo Because `setHandler` takes zero arguments.  Take a look at the LibraryLink tutorial.  On the C side, every LibraryLink function has the same signature.  Then you manually read all arguments, as needed.  `setHandler` doesn't read any arguments.  Just look at the examples which do take arguments and everything will be clear.