# How to get a script to print MaxMemoryUsed[] upon getting a system signal?

Tags: scripting, librarylink, unix

I want to instrument a *Mathematica* script so that, upon receiving any system signal (e.g. `SIGINT`, aka `Ctrl-C`) it will print<sup>1</sup> the value returned by `MaxMemoryUsed[]`.

I have read [this earlier answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32524/2464) and the `LibraryLink` docs, but I still can't figure out how to adapt the solution given in that answer so that `my_handler` can invoke `MaxMemoryUsed`, and print out its result.  IOW, I can't figure out what to replace the `???` below with so that `my_handler`'s printout shows the value returned by `MaxMemoryUsed[]`:

```c
void my_handler (int s) {

    fprintf(stderr, "MaxMemoryUsed[] returned: %d\n", ???);

    /* ------------------------------------------------------- */

    fprintf(stderr, "Received signal: %d\n", s);

    /* additional signal-handling code follows */
}
```

---

(One other possible way to achieve what I'm trying to do would be something like an `atexit` mechanism, but I have not been able to find anything like that for *Mathematica*.  Yet a third possibility would be to implement the script so that it periodically prints the value of `MaxMemoryUsed` to a file.  Unfortunately, for most of the script's lifetime, it is evaluating a single, irreducible *Mathematica* expression, and I don't know how to implement frequent periodic updating of an output file under these circumstances.  In any case, even if I knew how to do it, this last alternative is a distant second-best.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> preferably to stderr, but either stdout or some file is also OK.</sup>

Comment: I wouldn't do this with Ctrl-C.  If you just need to check memory usage periodically, you can set a scheduled task that will print it.  A signal handler won't be able to call back to the Mathematica kernel because it is invoked at an unpredictable time when the kernel may not be in a state that would allow this to work, even theoretically.  All it could do it set some flag that can be checked later *from Mathematica code*.  If you say that you are running Mathematica code that takes long and can't check for a flag, just scheduled tasks which use a pre-emptive evaluation.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for your comment.  To be clear: I don't want to use a signal *in order to* find out the memory usage.  Rather, I want to find out the memory being used *at the time* that the process receives a signal.  *I* do not send the signal to the process.  The signal is sent by the job-managing software (which I have no control over).  Therefore, the timing of the call to `MaxMemoryUsed` is critical.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I did not know about scheduled tasks.  I will now go read up on them.  Thanks for the pointer.